# Disable Last row of html tables checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the check box on two condition if there is only one row in the table or of last row's but it is not getting why is it not disabling.

HTML:

```
<table id="table_forms">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkView"/>View</td>

    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkView"/>View</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#table_forms tr:last input[type="checkbox"]').disabled;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  can use **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to set disabled property or use `[0]` to get dom element and set `disabled` property

```js
$('#table_forms tr:last input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_forms">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkView" />View</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkView" />View</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or

```js
$('#table_forms tr:last input[type="checkbox"]')[0].disabled = true;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_forms">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkView" />View</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkView" />View</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#table_forms tr:last input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```